# Visual Studio Code always asks for sudo permissions

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, permissions, sudo

Ok, so I've got a problem with VSCode where every time I try to save a file it asks me for sudo permission and it's really annoying and I can't make folders or files directly in the IDE. Can please someone help me?

[Screenshot from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chwpi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The running instance of VS Code doesn't seem to have write permission to the file you wish to save.

- Since the file is in the directory of user `uteu3`, first make sure that it is user `uteu3` that has started VS Code (it probably is, if `uteu3` is the user logged into the system).
- make sure `uteu3` is the owner of the file and change the permissions by opening a terminal and executing:

  ```
    sudo chown uteu3 filename && sudo chmod 664 filename
  ```

(Replace `filename` with actual path+name to the file.)

If this doesn't solve the problem, please execute the following two lines in a terminal and provide the output:

```
ps aux | grep visual-studio-code
stat -f '%A %a %N' filename
```

Since you indicate that this happens repeatedly also with other files, maybe several of the file permissions in your home directory are problematic. In that case, consider trying to fix them all. See for example: [Need to fix file permissions in a user's home directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/35076/need-to-fix-file-permissions-in-a-users-home-directory)
.